# How to release multiple mutexes in one call

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex, release, waitformultipleobjects

WinAPI provides us with WaitForMultipleObjects(..) function. Let's say we have to wait for all mutexes in array, then it would be great to have function that releases captured mutexes from array in one call. What made microsoft not to provide us with such a useful thing? What solution is best to release mutexes after WaitForMultipleObjects(..) if they are many enough?

Comment: You don't need to release them atomically so there's no need for such a function. And locking lots of mutexes at once is very unusual; deadlock awaits.

Comment: @AlanStokers Thanks! Let's say we have 5 mutexes captured with WaitForMultipleObjects(..) releasing them one by one would be a little bit messy.

Comment: @user2543574 It's trivial to write a function that takes a count and a `HANDLE*` (rather like `WaitForMultipleObjects`) and releases them in a loop.

Comment: @syam i know.. i know.. but i'm curious what microsoft says about it?

Comment: If you want to know *why* they didn't provide such a function, then I'm afraid your question is off-topic on SO because we could only *speculate* about their motivations, while SO is for *provable* facts. As to the *how* (the title of your question) I already gave an answer: just write that trivial function yourself. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raymond Chen of Microsoft may not have written about your exact topic, but he has written about others like it.  And as he says, "Every feature starts with -100 points."  There is no compelling need for the feature you are asking for; the code to implement it is too short, too unlikely to be used in very many places, and would be no better in a library than in the application.

People already complain that the Win32 API is bloated.  Be happy they didn't add this.